# Array to string conversion

Tags: php, mysql

looked around and everything seems to be more complex that what I am trying to do.

I have queried an item from a previous page and brought it forward.

```
$varVeh=$_POST['Veh_num'];
```

I echo that and it show the proper number....

I then want to use the name associated with that number in a table title. so I do another query:

```
$sql_vehName="select Veh_name from hc_vehicle_type where Veh_num=$varVeh";
$result_vehName = mysql_query($sql_vehName);
$vehName=mysql_fetch_assoc($result_vehName);
echo $vehName;  
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><td>Best Scores for</td><td>$vehName</td> </tr>";
```

Without using the fetch I get resource #6.

Comment: use `echo $vehName['Veh_name']`; - then I guess it works

Comment: `$vehName` is an (associative) array.  That's what you asked for when you called `mysql_fetch_assoc`.

Comment: @davidkonrad  That was fast... So I tried `$result_vehName = mysql_query($sql_vehName);
$vehName=mysql_fetch_assoc($result_vehName);
echo $vehName['vehName'];` but now get Undefined index: vehName  @RocketHazmat It was the only thing in my searching that would get rid of the resource #6    If I do a print_r it shows proper queried name. I simply just want that name to be displayed :(

Comment: I guess if I use the corrcet case it would all work..`echo $vehName['Veh_name'];` instead of `echo $vehName['vehName'];` Thanks!!!  is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign $vehName as an associative array.
What you can do is use the key that corresponds to your field name:

```
echo "<tr><td>Best Scores for</td><td>".$vehName['Veh_name']."</td> </tr>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql_vehName = "select Veh_name from hc_vehicle_type where Veh_num=$varVeh";
$result_vehName = mysql_query($sql_vehName);
$vehName = mysql_result($result_vehName,0);  
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><td>Best Scores for</td><td>$vehName</td> </tr>";
```